# Jax-RS response comes in HTML/text instead of JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a front-end react application, where i make a request to a REST Jax-RS backend server.

Here is the request being sent

```
  deletePost = (post) =>{
return deleter(config.restUrl + `posts/${post}`)
 }
```

Here i get the standart URL for my backend, with a 'deleter' function, which is just a standardized fetch delete method (which has also worked with other entities  as well).

Here is my Jax-RS resource:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id: [0-9]+}")
public Response deletePost(@HeaderParam("authorization") String token, @PathParam("id") Integer id) throws ResourceNotFoundException, AuthenticationException
{
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = authenticationFacade.authenticateBearerHeader(token);
    Post                  post                  = postFacade.delete(authenticationContext, id);
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(PostDTO.basic(post))).build();
}
```

The problem is that it gives me an error saying that the form is HTML/text:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type\u003dtext/html, type\u003dclass com.group3.sem3exam.rest.dto.PostDTO, genericType\u003dclass com.group3.sem3exam.rest.dto.PostDTO
```

Since it's implying that it is the `PostDTO` that has the error, I went to  check the basic method, which converts the entity into a Data Transfer Object, to be posted back to the client side.

```
   public static PostDTO basic(Post post)
{
    return new PostDTO(
            post.getId(),
            post.getContents(),
            post.getCreatedAt(),
            null,
            ImageDTO.list(post.getImages(), ImageDTO::withoutUser)
    );
    }
```

Here it just calls the method which returns a new instance of the object.

I have not seen this error before, and I'm not sure how to handle it?

Comment: Try to set the Accept header in the request to application/json.

Comment: Check if a message body writer has been registered for your application. If you are using Jersey and want to use Jackson as the body writer, you might need to have `register(JacksonFeature.class);` in your  `ApplicationConfig` or `ResourceConfig` class, that is affter adding the dependency in your dependency manager of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Gson().toJson(PostDTO.basic(post))).build();
```

Comment: Still gives an error unfortunately. As suspected, the difference doesn't really result in any change, since the functionality is the same. but +1 for effort.